# Colormaps not working for plots generated by scipy.griddata

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, scipy

## Summary

I have some randomly placed data which I would like to coerce into a grid, and display in a 3D surface plot with color. I mold the data using scipy.interpolate.griddata(). However, when using the method parameters of 'linear' or 'cubic', the surface only renders as the lowest valued color in the map.

## Things I've tried but haven't worked:

- Changing the boundaries of the grid.
- Normalizing the data.
- Displaying only 1 plot at a time.
- Plotting a variety of test functions (Ackley, Rastrigin, Himmelblau, Rosenbrock).

## Some Code:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from scipy.interpolate import griddata

def rosenbrock(x, y):
   # plotting test function
   return 100.0 * (y - x**2)**2 + (1.0 - x)**2

def plotGrid(x, y, z, title):
   # plot data as a 3D surface above a contour map
   cmap = plt.get_cmap('Spectral')
   fig = plt.figure()
   ax = Axes3D(fig)
   ax.plot_surface(x, y, z, cmap=cmap)
   ax.contour(     x, y, z, cmap=cmap, offset=0.0)
   ax.set_title(title)

def main():
   # generate a grid to interpolate between
   gx, gy = np.mgrid[-5:5:100j, -5:5:100j]
   # generate random points to mold into the desired grid
   p = np.random.rand(100, 2) * 10.0 - 5.0
   # find values for each random point pair
   v = rosenbrock(p[:,0], p[:,1])

   # interpolate the data into a grid
   g0 = griddata(p, v, (gx, gy), method='nearest')
   g1 = griddata(p, v, (gx, gy), method='linear')
   g2 = griddata(p, v, (gx, gy), method='cubic')

   # plot the data
   plotGrid(gx, gy, rosenbrock(gx, gy), 'True Grid')
   plotGrid(gx, gy, g0, 'Nearest')
   plotGrid(gx, gy, g1, 'Linear')
   plotGrid(gx, gy, g2, 'Cubic')

   plt.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

## Expectations

The above code creates a 3D plot for each grid type: True, Nearest, Linear, and Cubic.

In the 'True' and 'Nearest' plots the surface mesh renders as the expected colors based on the height of that data.

In the 'Linear' and 'Cubic' plots the surface mesh only renders as the lowest valued color (for the 'Spectral' cmap that color is magenta). I would like these plots to display the full range of color like the first 2 plots do.

I don't have enough reputation to post images, but here is a [link to an album](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXZIf.jpg) with all 4 plots.

Comment: You should see a warning similar to `UserWarning: Z contains NaN values. This may result in rendering artifacts.` which would explain this. You can get close by setting the minimum and maximum of the data as the limits of the colormap, `ax.plot_surface(x, y, z, cmap=cmap, vmin=np.nanmin(z), vmax=np.nanmax(z))`; but for a propper solution one would need to get rid of the NaN values.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest That was exactly the issue. NaN values are causing artifacts. Thank you for your help.